# ActionFilter Return Http Status Code with Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an `ActionFilterAttribute` in which I am checking for a valid license. I would like to return a 401 error along with a message. Right now, I have the following implementation:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
    ...
    // return errror (short-circuit)
    context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(401);
    return;
}
```

How can I also pass a message? Inside my controllers, I would do the following:

```
return Unauthorized("Some error message");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core source code is available on GitHub, where it shows that the implementation for the `Unauthorized` method used in a controller looks like this ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/5.0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L1764-L1765)):

```
public virtual UnauthorizedObjectResult Unauthorized([ActionResultObjectValue] object value)
    => new UnauthorizedObjectResult(value);
```

You can emulate this inside of your `OnActionExecuting` implementation, like this:

```
context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult("Some error message");
```